# by viewmodels versus hiltviewmodel

Tags: android, android-jetpack, dagger-hilt

When I want to share a view model between various views I would use `by viewmodels`. I recently began looking into hilt and was wondering if `hiltviewmodel` would accomplish the same thing? That is to allow me to share a single(same instance) of a viewmodel?

Answer (score 7):

by viewModels():

1. property delegate.
2. the first time create, next time return the same instance(in the same scope, the scope is the same activity)

= hiltViewModel():

1. only used in @Composable annotated function.
2. the first time create, next time return the same instance(in the same scope, the scope is NavGraph, if no graph, fragment/activity)

you 'd best build a demo and practise it, and log the instance to see if the same instance.

```
val viewModel: ViewModelA by viewModels()

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContent {
        HiltDemoTheme {
            val viewModel2: ViewModelA = hiltViewModel()
            val viewModel3: ViewModelA = viewModel()
            val viewModel4: ViewModelA by viewModels()
            Log.d("Jeck", "$viewModel")
            Log.d("Jeck", "$viewModel2")
            Log.d("Jeck", "$viewModel3")
            Log.d("Jeck", "$viewModel4")// the four get the same instance
            Surface(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                color = MaterialTheme.colors.background
            ) {
                
            }
        }
    }
```

Documentation:
[Hilt and Navigation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/libraries#hilt-navigation)

> When using Navigation Compose, always use the hiltViewModel composable
> function to obtain an instance of your @HiltViewModel annotated
> ViewModel. This works with fragments or activities that are annotated
> with @AndroidEntryPoint.

Comment: When to use `hiltViewModel`?

Answer (score 0):

The ViewModel annotated with `@HiltViewModel` will be available for creation by the `HiltViewModelFactory` and can be retrieved by default in an Activity or Fragment annotated with `@AndroidEntryPoint` by using `ViewModelProvider` or the `by viewModels()`.

Also, `by viewModels` returns a property delegate to access ViewModel by default scoped to the fragment. Remember `viewModels` is not only used with Hilt, but it can be used to provide simple ViewModel instances as well when not using Hilt.

On the other hand, `@HiltViewModel`, tells Hilt that this ViewModel can be injected into other classes marked with `@AndroidEntryPoint` as well as allowing Hilt to inject other dependencies into this ViewModel.

---

> All Hilt ViewModels are provided by the ViewModelComponent which follows the same lifecycle as a ViewModel, and as such, can survive configuration changes. To scope a dependency to a ViewModel use the @ViewModelScoped annotation.
> A @ViewModelScoped type will make it so that a single instance of the scoped type is provided across all dependencies injected into the ViewModel. Other instances of a ViewModel that request the scoped instance will receive a different instance.
> If a single instance needs to be shared across various ViewModels, then it should be scoped using either @ActivityRetainedScoped or @Singleton.

[Source: https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-jetpack#viewmodelscoped]

---

And if the shared/single ViewModel is among different fragments, you could bind the lifecycle of the injected ViewModel to the parent Activity by `by activityViewModels`.

---

More information:
https://dagger.dev/api/latest/dagger/hilt/android/lifecycle/HiltViewModel.html &
https://dagger.dev/hilt/view-model.html &
https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-jetpack